# Naming a pandas dataframe in a python function

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I am writing a function in python and I want to be able to rename a pandas data frame within the function.

For example:

```
def a(test):
    df=df*2
    test=df
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you mean rename the columns of the dataframe ?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. Where does df come from? What result do you expect from calling this function? Why not just return df from the function?

Answer (score 0):

To naame a Pandas DataFrame, you just need to execute:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(#insert data here)
```

`df` will become the name of your DataFrame.